# Split all values in column and store them in a single numeric vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R and I want to create a single numeric vector by splitting all of the character values in a specific column and then appending them to the vector or list. The values in the column are all comma-separated numbers and there are rows with missing values or `NA`.

**Current data**

```
id col
1  2,6,10
2  NA
3  5, 10 
4  1
```

**Final vector**

```
# v <- c(2, 6, 10, 5, 10, 1)
# v
[1] 2 6 10 5 10 1
```

I'm able to do this by iterating through all the values in the column but I know this isn't the most efficient way since R is made to work easily with vectors. Is there a better way to do this?

```
v <- c()
for(val in df$col){
  if(!is.na(val)){
    ints <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(val, ",")))
    v <- c(v, ints)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the answer in your code since all the functions you are using are vectorised.

```
v <- as.numeric(na.omit(unlist(strsplit(df$col, ','))))
v
#[1]  2  6 10  5 10  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate_rows(col) %>% na.omit() %>% pull(col) %>% as.numeric() -> v
v
[1]  2  6 10  5 10  1
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id col   
  <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 2,6,10
2     2 NA    
3     3 5, 10 
4     4 1
```

Comment: This works but I want the final values to be of `numeric` type so I can add an additional pipe at the end `%>% as.numeric `.

Comment: @fastlanes, have edited the answer, just need to add `as.numeric` to the code